# how do i create a contrail for a mouse with html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a website in where a word "lean" follows your cursor. there are two issues i have that I'm struggling with. first: the `<div id="circle">lean</div>`(see html below) element only works when there is text above it. my second problem is that the word is stuck in the right corner and wont move.

here is my code:

```js
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  circle.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  circle.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  color: #8A2BE2;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
a
<div id="circle">
  lean
</div>
```

is it possible that this has something to do with the version of the html files? i have largely created this html from a combination of other old tutorials. sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still a novice programmer.

Comment: It still works if there is no text above it, and what do you mean that it is stuck on the right corner?

Comment: Seems to be working fine (also without text before) in Chrome 99, Firefox 98, Safari 15